SQL query to summarize Code Status Movement values
This is my current setup - we're using an orderlineshistory table that is a temporal table
drop table #Orderlines
drop table #Orders
drop table #OrderlinesHistory

create table #Orders
(Id uniqueidentifier
,OrderDate datetime
,TotalValue Decimal(9,2)
)
create table #Orderlines
(Id uniqueidentifier
,OrderId uniqueidentifier
,ActivationDate dateTime
,Value decimal (9,2)
,Ecode varchar(50)
,EcodeStatusId int
,ValidFrom dateTime
,ValidTo DateTime)

create Table #OrderlinesHistory
(Id uniqueidentifier
,OrderId uniqueidentifier
,ActivationDate dateTime
,Value decimal (9,2)
,Ecode varchar(50)
,EcodeStatusId int
,ValidFrom dateTime
,ValidTo DateTime)


insert #Orders
(id,OrderDate,TotalValue)
values ('43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-10-26',40)
,('3D24980B-B83F-4D8B-DE13-08DCF81D15AD','2024-11-25',25)

insert #Orderlines
(id,OrderId,ActivationDate,Ecode,EcodeStatusId,ValidFrom,ValidTo,Value)
values
('2987bdba-5345-4154-b8bd-41bc0186eefc','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-10-26','ECODE-0',1, '2024-10-26',null,10)
,('2FAC6F53-D6E0-4C99-8C29-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-11-01','ECODE-1',2, '2024-11-05',null,10)
,('A5776A49-9A00-4450-8C2B-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-11-01','ECODE-2',3, '2024-11-17',null,10)
,('05B58778-94BA-4B85-8C27-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-11-01','ECODE-3',4, '2024-11-30',null,10)
,('F3639DD8-3515-47EC-2A3B-08DCD97CAC6C','3D24980B-B83F-4D8B-DE13-08DCF81D15AD','2024-11-25','ECODE-1-A',1, '2024-11-25',null,25)

insert #OrderlinesHistory
(id,OrderId,ActivationDate,Ecode,EcodeStatusId,ValidFrom,ValidTo,Value)
values
('2FAC6F53-D6E0-4C99-8C29-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-10-26',null,null, '2024-10-26','2024-10-28', 10)
,('2FAC6F53-D6E0-4C99-8C29-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-11-01','ECODE-1',1, '2024-10-28','2024-11-05',10)

,('A5776A49-9A00-4450-8C2B-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-10-26',null,null, '2024-10-26','2024-10-28',10)
,('A5776A49-9A00-4450-8C2B-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-11-01','ECODE-2',1, '2024-10-28','2024-11-17',10)

,('05B58778-94BA-4B85-8C27-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-10-26',null,null, '2024-10-26','2024-10-28',10)
,('05B58778-94BA-4B85-8C27-08DCD62AB512','43D7E9F9-7688-4905-BC69-08DCF81D15BB','2024-11-01','ECODE-3',1, '2024-10-28','2024-11-30',10)


I would like to summarise the status of the ecodes for the month that the code moved status. So in our scenario. The first order was placed in October for 4 codes and the status of those codes in October were 1 (Live).  One of each of codes then moved to their current status of 2 (Redeemed), 3 (cancelled) and 4 (expired) on different dates in  November and 1 code remained Live. Another order was placed for 1 25 Pound Code in November . The report I am looking for should summarize as per the image  (see image below)

This is what I have tried
-- Summarize data by OrderMonth and Status
WITH OrderMonths AS (
    SELECT
        FORMAT(o.OrderDate, 'MMM-yy') AS OrderMonth,
        o.TotalValue AS OrderTotal,
        h.EcodeStatusId,
        h.Value
    FROM
        #Orders o
    JOIN
        #Orderlines ol ON o.Id = ol.OrderId
    JOIN
        #OrderlinesHistory h ON ol.Id = h.Id
    WHERE
        h.ValidFrom <= o.OrderDate
        AND (h.ValidTo IS NULL OR h.ValidTo >= o.OrderDate)
),
StatusSummary AS (
    SELECT
        OrderMonth,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EcodeStatusId = 1 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Live,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EcodeStatusId = 2 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Redeemed,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EcodeStatusId = 3 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS cancelled
    FROM
        OrderMonths
    GROUP BY
        OrderMonth
)
SELECT
    sm.OrderMonth,
    SUM(om.OrderTotal) AS OrderTotal,
    sm.Live,
    sm.Redeemed,
    sm.cancelled
FROM
    StatusSummary sm
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT FORMAT(OrderDate, 'MMM-yy') AS OrderMonth, TotalValue AS OrderTotal FROM #Orders) om
    ON sm.OrderMonth = om.OrderMonth
GROUP BY
    sm.OrderMonth, sm.Live, sm.Redeemed, sm.cancelled;


Can you be more precise about this? What happens in month Dec-24 if an order stays Live? What does ActivationDate represent, if not relevant please remove? What does Ecode represent, is it the same as EcodeStatusId and if so why both columns? And what is OrderTotal as compared to Live?

Put it this way: why does this much simpler query not fit what you need https://dbfiddle.uk/TFALbwvM

ActivationDate is not relevant in the summary data - it was put there to show that if the orderlines table changes - then a history record is created. The Ecode is a unique Code that has a monetary value and is used to purchase goods. The status of the ecode is live until it has been used to purchase goods then it becomes redeemed. The orderTotal is OrderValue of the all the ecodes purchased for One Order. The 30 pound order has 3 ecodes - they can have different statuses but in October all their statuses were "Live" they were then redeemed in November. I will post another image for Dec data

@Charlieface also and orderlines ecode can move from live to redeemed or cancelled in the same month it was ordered

So does what I offered you work? https://dbfiddle.uk/wokgtpSl And what do you expect to happen in Dec-24

@Charlieface - this doesn't seem to work - please see the update edit above - I have added a fourth orderline for the 1st order and added more of an explaination around the summary values

I don't understand the logic, please be clear. How does Dec come in, when none of those rows are in Dec? Do you perhaps want some kind of running total? For example, count all rows which are Live as part of a month, until they become Redeemed or Cancelled? Please explain the exact steps you would use to get your result when calculating by hand.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
